# Python Pandas value counts for multiple columns and generate graph from the result

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, graph

I have a csv to read from as follows

```
A   B   C
Sam 123 PID-213
Sam 145 PID-432
Sam 123 PID-546
Dan 786 PID-321
Dan 897 PID-432
```

and I want a group as below: count of unique B elements and Pids. (Bis 2 because 123 is repeated twice so)

```
A   B   C
Sam 2   3   
Dan 2   2
```

And from the above plot a graph as below :  and also a pie chart from column A and B and save it in a pdf in 2 different page.

[image: Bar graph]

How do i achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [18]: df.groupby('A')['B','C'].nunique().plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[18]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xb7d7a90>
```

[image]

Comment: When I try in PyCharm, by default all are having the same colors. How to assign colors?

Comment: @vikasns, does it work properly in Jupyter / ipython?

Comment: I haven't tried it. But in PyCharm it doesn't work. Would you be so kind enough to tell me how to do it Pycharm?

Comment: No problem, Thanks.!